# Force Test-connection to use IPv4

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have a script that tests for hosts using `Test-Connection`. If successful it proceeds, if not it states the host is offline.

Problem is, our enterprise has IPv6 entries in our DNS zones. Hosts that register in DNS with IPv6 are responding first and since IPv6 isn't in use, `Test-Connection` states that they are Offline. However, good old fashion `ping` with the `-4` switch works fine and they respond.

I have been looking to find a switch to force `Test-Connection` to use IPv4, but can't find anything. I can't make massive changes to DNS zones to purge IPv6 records because the host will simply re-register. I don't have control over that.

Ping works fine but I am having trouble with it because I can't get it to return simple TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

Run `ping` and check the `$LASTEXITCODE` [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx):

```psh
& ping -4 -n 1 $server >$null
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
    'success'
} else {
    "$server not accessible"
}
```

You could also do a name lookup first, restrict it to IPv4 addresses (A records only), and run `Test-Connection` on the IPv4 address:

```psh
$ip = & nslookup -type=A $server |
      Select-Object -Skip 4 -First 1 |
      ForEach-Object { $_.Split(':')[1].Trim() }

Test-Connection $ip
```

If you have at least Windows 8 you could use [`Resolve-DnsName`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590781%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) instead of `nslookup`, which is a little more PoSh:

```psh
$ip = Resolve-DnsName -Type A $server |
      Select-Object -Expand IPAddress
```

Comment: The first bit of code "& ping -4 -n 1....." worked perfectly. Thanks for the help. Not sure if this is how I show the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Test-Connection supports an -IPV4 switch to force IPV4 with PowerShell 7. I'm not sure when this functionality was added.

However, Test-Connection for Windows PowerShell apparently does not support the -IPV4 switch to this day.

Someday the schism will be resolved.